# Why does my mac now greedily delete?

Tags: macos, catalina

When deleting one character it often deletes two.

It is not the key repeat as I have set that really slow, which is painful when tabbing between apps and moving the curser now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it do that in every program - or just one? - Have you tried with a different keyboard - does it still do it?

Comment: @jksoegaard several including terminal, which is native osx. Not tried a separate keyboard - am using a macbook pro (2019)